# Evaluating the error with respect Numerical Differentiation

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Hi guys i am attempting the following question

[image]

Therefore based on the points given i decided to evaluate using the taylor series expansion

$$f(x+2h) = f(x) + 2hf'(x)+\frac{2h^2 f''(x)}{2!}+\frac{2h^3f'''(x)}{3!}$$
In a similar manner i evaluated at 
$$f(x-2h) = f(x) - 2hf'(x)+\frac{2h^2 f''(x)}{2!}-\frac{2h^3f'''(x)}{3!}$$

I then made f'''(x) the subject of the equation

$$f'''(x) = \frac{6}{h^3}[f(x+2h)-f(x)-2hf'(x)-h^2f''(x)]$$

Now the error is given by the following the

$$f'''(x) - D'''_h f(x)$$

Im not sure how to evaluate the error and show the order can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function 
$$
g(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}2
$$
is odd in $h$, its Taylor series is composed of the odd degree terms of the Taylor series of $f$,
$$
g(h)=f'(x)h+\frac16f'''(x)h^3+\frac1{120}f^{(5)}(x)h^5+O(h^7).
$$
The divided difference expression can be written as
$$
\frac{g(2h)-2g(h)}{h^3}=\frac16f'''(x)[2^3-2]+\frac1{120}f^{(5)}(x)[2^5-2]h^2+\frac1{7!}f^{(7)}(x)[2^7-2]h^4+...
\\
=f'''(x)+\frac14f^{(5)}(x)h^2+\frac1{40}f^{(7)}(x)h^4+...
$$

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+h^3f'''(x)/6+O(h^4)
$.

This gives
$f(x+h)-f(x-h)
=2hf'(x)+h^3f'''(x)/3+O(h^4)
$
and,
with $2h$ for $h$,
$f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)
=4hf'(x)+8h^3f'''(x)/3+O(h^4)
$.

Combining these,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+2f(x-h)-f(x-2h)\\
=f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)-2(f(x+h)-f(x-h))\\
=4hf'(x)+8h^3f'''(x)/3+O(h^4)-2(2hf'(x)+h^3f'''(x)/3+O(h^4))\\
=4hf'(x)-4hf'(x)+8h^3f'''(x)/3-2h^3f'''(x)/3+O(h^4))\\
=2h^3f'''(x)+O(h^4))\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\text{so}\\
D_h'''(x)
&=\dfrac{f(x+2h)-2f(x+h)+2f(x-h)-f(x-2h)}{2h^3}\\
&=f'''(x)+O(h)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: cohen im required to prove that the error is O(h^2)

Comment: Replace the $O(h^4)$ term by $h^4f''''(x)/24+O(h^5)$ and the $h^4$ terms will cancel out leaving $O(h^5)$ which becomes $O(h^2)$ when divided by $h^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$f(x+k h)=f(x)+h k f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 k^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 k^3
   f^{(3)}(x)+$$ $$\frac{1}{24} h^4 k^4 f^{(4)}(x)+\frac{1}{120} h^5 k^5
   f^{(5)}(x)+\frac{1}{720} h^6 k^6 f^{(6)}(x)+O\left(h^7\right)$$ the numerator write
$$2 h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^5 f^{(5)}(x)+O\left(h^7\right)$$ Divide hy $2h^3$ to get
$$f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{4} h^2 f^{(5)}(x)+O\left(h^4\right)=f^{(3)}(x)+O\left(h^2\right)$$

Comment: how do you evaluate the error?